# Trying to make ion-datetime’s style the same as the ion-input style

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-vue

I want to make the `ion-datetime` to have the same style as the input style to make my design consistent.

To be clear, please have a look at the image below.

[image: visual explanation]

I've tried to modify the CSS properties the same way I created the input style but I can't get the text to be vertically centered. Applying `vertical-align: middle` or `display: flex` with `align-items: center` doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Here is my current CSS for both the input and the datetime:

```css
ion-input,
ion-datetime {
  background-color: #131313;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 1.25rem !important;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

And here is my template if needed:

```html
<IonRow>
  <IonCol>
    <IonItem lines="none" class="ion-no-padding">
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Birth Place</IonLabel>
      <IonInput v-model="data.birthplace" />
    </IonItem>
  </IonCol>
  <IonCol>
    <IonItem lines="none" class="ion-no-padding">
      <IonLabel position="stacked">Birth Date</IonLabel>
      <IonDatetime id="datetime-input" v-model="data.birthdate" />
    </IonItem>
  </IonCol>
</IonRow>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer, after reading the docs carefully and analyzing the structure of the DOM from the devtools, I realize that the text was encapsulated inside the shadow-dom.

[image: visual explanation]

In order to make it work, I must first [expose the part](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts#exposing-a-part) using `::part`, so instead of doing it like this which is doesn't work:

```css
ion-datetime {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I changed it to this:

```css
ion-datetime {
  ...
}

ion-datetime::part(text) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It works just like what I wanted now.